# StringRequest for loop

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

how i can use for loop  with StringRequest to get all data in mysQl data base so this my code                                    `

```
      StringRequest jsonObjectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                        if (!error) {
                            for(int i=0;i<jObj.length();i++){

                            String user = jObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi     " + user +", You are login!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // Launch User activity


                           // finish();
                        }} else {

                            String errorMsg =jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }`
```

Comment: Why isn't your code working?

Comment: @Rotwang it works but not getting all data in mysQl data base

Comment: you have no code here that inserts your data into the sqlite database.... and your question is a bit broad. Have you setup your database? do you have code which can perform an insert to a specific table? all your showing us is that you made a request. There are plenty of tutorials available for learning how to use Sqlite in android, you can find one https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Comment: @inner_class7 i already have data in mysQl but not all diplayed and i'am using volley to insert into data base

Comment: okay, well the problem is you are not sharing with us the insert or read code for the database so its tough for us to guess why you aren't getting all rows. If you share this info i am happy to help solve the problem and offer advice on optimizing inserts or improving a query

Comment: @inner_class7 not that what i mean but i read Vertical Lines and Horizontal line for the hospital and add name and insert into data base all i need to know how to read all data from data base